# (MS) WebDav errors list anywhere?

Tags: sharepoint, file-upload, webdav

I'm getting the following error when uploading a file to a Sharepoint 2010 list, using a WebRequest with the PUT verb.

X-MSDAVEXT_Error: 327704; Unable%20to%20complete%20this%20operation%2e%20%20Please%20contact%20your%20administrator%2e

There is pretty much no information about that specific error code (327704). I came up with the following page by Microsoft, which says that due to the existing HTTP errors not being enough to handle all file operation scenarios, they created that MSDAVEXT error.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc250064(v=prot.10).aspx

However, after googling for two hours, I cannot find a description of that error, or ANY of the extended errors they supposedly handle.

Here's a link to the MS WebDav implementation index, and of course, the "Errors" link under the E letter is not a link.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc250260(v=PROT.10).aspx

Does anyone know about these extended errors, or know where I can find more information about this? Thanks .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't link answering my own questions, but just in case it helps anyone else, I was able to find a couple of pages that detail just the general cause of groups/ranges of Extended WebDAV errors, here they are:

The link originally included in my question:

[MS-WDV - Extended Error Handling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc250064%28v=prot.10%29.aspx)

[MS-WEBDAVE - Currently defined WebDAV Extended Errors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd906458%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

[WEBDAV Protocol Status Codes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa126058%28v=EXCHG.65%29.aspx)

WHY the "Currently defined WebDAV extended errors is not linked from the Extended Error Handling is beyond me. It does not even detail each error code, but a "range of them". I still don't have access to the Sharepoint logs as to see if the logged error does indeed give more information about the actual server problem, but I hope this helps someone.